# Каким образом можно включить аудит пользователю приложения в базе данных Оракл?

Tags: oracle

Имеется СУБД Оракл, аудит пользователям включены, но программисты заходят под пользователем приложения , для пользователей приложений аудиты не включены. 
Вопрос, каким образом можно увидеть что выполняет сотрудник заходя под пользователем приложения, как включить аудит ?

Answer (score 1):

До Oracle 10g аудит отключен по умолчанию, но его можно включить, установив статический параметр `AUDIT_TRAIL` в файле `init.ora`. 
В Oracle 11g аудит включен для некоторых привилегий системного уровня.

Посмотреть параметры аудита можно:

```
SQL> show parameter audit;
```

Должны увидеть такую картину:

```
NAME                    TYPE            VALUE
----------------------  ------------    -------------
audit_file_dest         string          ?/rdbms/audit
audit_sys_operations    boolean         FALSE
audit_syslog_level      string          NONE
audit_trail             string          DB
transaction_auditing    boolean         TRUE
```

Нам конкретно нужен параметр `audit_trail`.

`AUDIT_TRAIL` может иметь следующие значения:

```
AUDIT_TRAIL = 
{
  NONE or FALSE| 
  OS           | 
  DB or TRUE   | 
  DB_EXTENDED  | 
  XML          |
  XML_EXTENDED 
}
```

В следующем списке приведено описание каждого значения:

- `NONE or FALSE` => Аудит отключен. По умолчанию до Oracle 10g.
- `DB or TRUE`    => Аудит включен, все записи аудита хранятся в базе данных. По умолчанию от Oracle 11g.
- `DB_EXTENDED`   => То же, что DB, но столбцы `SQL_BIND` и `SQL_TEXT` также заполнены.
- `XML` => Аудит включен, все записи аудита хранятся в виде файлов ОС в формате `XML`.
- `XML_EXTENDED` => То же, что и `XML`, но столбцы `SQL_BIND` и `SQL_TEXT` также заполнены.
- `OS` => Аудит включен, и все записи аудита направляются в файл операционной системы, указанный в `AUDIT_FILE_DEST`.

В Oracle 10g Release 1 `DB_EXTENDED` был использован вместо `DB, EXTENDED`. Опции XML были представлены в Oracle 10g Release 2. Параметр `AUDIT_FILE_DEST` указывает каталог ОС, используемый для контрольного журнала при использовании параметров ОС, `XML и XML_EXTENDED`. Это также место для всех обязательных проверок, указанных параметром `AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS`. Статический параметр `AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS` включает или отключает аудит операций, выполняемых пользователями, подключающимися с привилегиями `SYSDBA` или `SYSOPER`, включая пользователя `SYS`.

Собственно как же включить аудит?

Нужно запустить `sqlplus` и выполнить команду:

```
SQL>ALTER SYSTEM SET audit_trail = DB_EXTENDED SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

Управление аудитом:

Синтаксис команды аудита:

```
audit {statement_option|privilege_option} [by user] [by {session|access}] [whenever {successful|not successful}]
```

Есть три уровня аудита, которые могут быть проверены:

- **Statement level**

Аудит будет проводиться на уровне утверждений. Утверждения, которые могут быть проверены, находятся в `STMT_AUDIT_OPTION_MAP`:

```
    SQL>audit table by scott;
```

Аудиторские записи можно найти в `DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS`:

```
SQL>select * from DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS;
```

- **Object level**

Аудит будет проводиться на уровне объектов. Эти объекты могут быть проверены: таблицы, представления, последовательности, пакеты, хранимые процедуры и хранимые функции.

```
    SQL> audit insert, update, delete on scott.emp by hr;
```

Аудиторские записи можно найти в `DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS`:

```
SQL> select * from DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS;
```

- **Privilege level**

Аудит будет проводиться на уровне привилегий.
Все системные привилегии, которые находятся в `SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP`, могут быть проверены.

```
    SQL> audit create tablespace, alter tablespace by all;
```

Аудиторские записи можно найти в `DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS`.

```
SQL> select * from DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS;
```

PS. Материал для самообучения:

[AUDIT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm)

[Auditing Database Activity](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000)

[Configuring and Administering Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#BABCFIHB)